# How to add text inside existing lines

Tags: python

So I already know how to open / read from a file line.. for example here's what I wrote so far.

```
a=0
file_paths = sys.argv[1:]
for path in file_paths:
        a=1
if(a==0):
    while True:
        print('\nSpecify where the path of the code is')
        print('Example /home/user/desktop/code.txt \n')
        path=input('Input Here: ')
        if os.path.isfile(path)==True:
            break
        else:
            print('No files found. Please try again')

with open(path,encoding="utf-8") as f:
    src=f.readlines()
    f.close
```

This opens the file given and is able to read it from the given input. However in order to actually use this for the purpose I have in mind I want to be able to add text inside of what it reads..

For example upon running the script it'll ask you for the file

`Input Here: Test`

So it opens and reads the file `Test`

Is it possible to make it add specific text inbetween the lines that it reads?

(Sorry for this being long btw I'll try to make a short example)

For instance: Say the contents of `Test` were as follows

```
12345678 87654321
```

would it be possible to output / print after reading to

```
!12345678 - 234 !87654321
```

I've been searching for examples of this for around a week with no luck, not sure if I'm blind or what so I gave up and flocked over here. Any examples / thoughts would be appreciated. If not that's okay as well.

Edit: To be more specific (as per requested) the file structure I'm trying to use will always look similar to this: inside of the `Test` file it would look somewhat like this.

```
12345678 87654321
12312332 84173183
12378764 75446774
```

and aiming to output something along the lines of (it wont always be 3 or 2 numbers, just looking to add the newer parts as seen below)

```
!12345678 - 234 !87654321
!12312332 - 234 !84173183
!12378764 - 234 !75446774
```

Comment: It depends on the structure of the file. Is it always 2 numbers and you want to always add the same characters around it? If not, please provide a more detailed example. Try to avoid commentary that does not relate to the question

Comment: So the specific file structure would always be as follows 

`12345678 12345678
12345678 12345678
12345678 12345678`

Edit; this did not work well in a comment gonna update this in the actual question itself

Comment: Is your goal to overwrite the existing file with the new info, or to make a new version in a new file? (I would definitely recommend making a new version, at least until you are sure you will not need to backtrack.)

Comment: @ramzeek so the goal is to add the modified text into a new file, I'm confident I can write that part myself, it's just adding the text to the read file that I'm stuck on.

edit: I can also always just have it print to Terminal for simplicity as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways you can do this. One simple way is to split each line by spaces and put in the surrounding text in a print statement:

```py
for line in src:
  line_parts = line.split()
  print(f'!{line_parts[0]} - 234 !{line_parts[1]}')
```

This obviously assumes you know the structure of the file and it always has only, or at least, 2 parts separated by a space.

Another method would be to use regex but this is more complicated than is needed for such a task.

With some edits to your code to make it more pythonic, it may look something like:

```py
path = sys.argv[1]

while not os.path.isfile(path):
    print('No files found.')
    print('\nSpecify where the path of the code is')
    print('Example /home/user/desktop/code.txt \n')
    path = input('Input Here: ')     

with open(path,encoding="utf-8") as f:
    src = f.readlines()

for line in src:
  line_parts = line.split()
  print(f'!{line_parts[0]} - 234 !{line_parts[1]}')
```

Assuming only the first command line argument is a path

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear, I updated my answer with a revision of your code making it a little more pythonic. If you have any questions let me know

Comment: No more questions, your answer helped me miles along even before the edits :) 

I might have done it a weird way but it works! So thank you